# Code crashing with following error

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, ios5, ios4

My application is using apple connect library. I started my application 8 hours ago and then again when I switched to my application from background to foreground it hangs and shows the following error:

ACM Error: Sign In dialog is already shown
:failedRefreshingACMTokenWithError : Sign In dialog is already shown